# Посимвольно считывание с консоли С++

Tags: c++

Как считывать строку с консоли посимвольно? То есть, пользователь вводит символ, программа тут же прибавляет его к строке, пока символ не станет равным \n

Answer (score 1):

Можно читать

```
char c;
while(cin.get(c)) {
    if (с == '\n') break;
```

или просто

```
while((c = cin.get()) != '\n')...
```

только во втором версии должен быть `int`, а не `char`.

Comment: Я бы добавил вариант `cin >> noskipws;`, после чего можно читать просто как `while(cin>>c)...`